# Can I disable Xbox on Asus Laptop

Tags: windows-8

I have an Asus laptop and the Xbox screen keeps popping up when I'm trying to perform other functions.

I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd>  <kbd>delete</kbd>  to escape and go through task manager to get back to my work.

Is there a way to disable Xbox?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the notification?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a program that registers itself as one to start automatically when your system is booted.

[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) is good for disabling auto-starting programs.
[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) has a built-in utility to do this as well, though it is not as comprehensive as Autoruns, but may do the job.